# Problem with finding a sole number in an unsorted array

Tags: java, arrays, methods

A method which receives an array, which is unsorted, and consists of pairs of adjacent equal numbers as well as exactly one number which does not have a pair. For example -

```
int [] a = {6,6,18,18,-4,-4,12,9,9};
int [] c = {8,-7,-7,3,3,0,0,10,10,5,5,4,4};
```

The code has to return the index and the number itself.

Now the question is about time complexity which I know it can be done by O(logn) to solve this, but my code half works:

```
public static int findSingle (int [] a) {
    int high = a.length-1;
    int low = 0;
    int mid = 0;
    int found = 0;
    mid = ((high-low)/2);
    while (mid >= 1) {
        if (a[mid] != a[mid-1])
            low = mid +1;
        mid =((high - low)/2);
        if (mid == 1)
            found = a[mid];
        if (a[mid] == a[mid-1])
            high = mid-1;
        mid = ((high - low)/2);
    }
    return found;
}
```

Now given this array:

```
int [] d = {8,8,-7,3,3,0,0,10,10,5,5,4,4};
```

It says that the number is in the 8th element, which is obviously not true, and in some arrays it also makes mistakes. What's the problem?

Edit: I've noticed I should've assigned "mid" to be high + low/2 but it doesn't solve the issue either way.

Comment: You can use binary search on an unsorted array in this context, but there are some obvious bugs in this code. I'm working on an answer.

Comment: dbl, the instruction as I said was to find the sole number in the array, with time complexity of logn.
ThisIsAQuestion, thank you.

Comment: When you say "_which is unsorted_" do you mean that **all** entries are potentially unsorted (e.g. `{3,1,-2,-2,1,99,3}` would be possible), or that – as happens to be the case with your examples – the pairs are **always** adjacent, and it is the **pairs** that are unsorted?

Comment: @TripeHound, the array will always have pairs, and they always be close to eachother.
For example, {4,4,-2,-2,5} is viable but {4,5,4,-2,-2} isn't.

Comment: You need to find the number and index of that number, which doesn't have a paired entry?

Comment: @BeUndead yes, I need to find 7 in {-2, -2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 7, 200, 200} and 7's index.

Comment: @Ohande OK. For future clarity, I would say "_Where the pairs must be **adjacent** (or **next**) to each other._". The problem with "_close to each other_" is that because it _doesn't_ use "adjacent" or "next", most people would say `{4,5,4,-2,-2}` _would_ satisfy the condition, because the two `4`s _are_ close to each other.

Comment: @TripeHound noted, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there's a few problems with your code.

```
while (mid >= 1)
```

Why is mid being less than or equal to 1 your exit condition? You want your exit condition to be when you found your value which could be anywhere in your array, not just at the beginning. I'm going to change the exit condition to be based on `high` and `low`, like in a normal binary search.

```
mid = ((high-low)/2);
```

First, this formula does not find the number in the middle of `high` and `low`. This should be `((high+low)/2)`. Additionally, the nature of these lists makes it very important to keep the parity of `mid` consistent. I'm going to ensure `mid` stays even by adding `mid += mid%2;` when `mid` is set.

```
low = mid +1;
...
high = mid-1;
```

Again, the parity of `high` and `low` is very important. Both should always remain even. We know that `mid` is even, so `high` and `low` should not be offset by `mid` by +/-1.

```
if (mid == 1)
    found = a[mid];
```

This is the biggest problem in your code. First, are you trying to find the index of the single number or the value of the single number? You say you're looking for the index, but your code is finding `a[mid]` which is a value. My code below finds the index, but this can easily be altered. Second, you're only doing this when `mid` is 1. This means your code will always either return 0 or `a[1]`.

A couple other notes. There is no reason to set `mid` twice per loop and check both `a[mid] != a[mid-1]` and `a[mid] == a[mid-1]`. Instead, set mid once per loop, check one of those conditions, and use `if/else`. Also, there's no reason to use `found`. Instead, just use the value of `high` or `low` when the loop exits, now that it's exiting properly.

The final code:

```
public static int findSingle (int [] a) {
    int high = a.length-1;
    int low = 0;
    int mid = 0;

    while (high != low) {
        mid = ((high + low) / 2);
        mid += mid%2;

        if (a[mid] != a[mid-1])
            low = mid;
        else
            high = mid - 2;
    }
    return high;
}
```

I haven't tested this thoroughly, but from the few test cases I did look at it seems to be working.

**Edit:**

Turns out there was a bug (thanks Alex Rudenko). Fixed version:

```
public static int findSingle (int [] a) {
    int high = a.length-1;
    int low = 0;
    int mid = 0;
    while (high != low) {
        mid = ((high + low) / 2);
        mid -= mid%2;
        if (a[mid] == a[mid+1])
            low = mid + 2;
        else
            high = mid;
    }
    return high;
}
```

Comment: Bless you, it does work. My initial code needs to return the value and the index, but I get why it didn't return the index. What I'm failing to understand is why returning high makes it work?

Comment: @Ohande The only time the code will get to the `return high` line is when `high == low` which means both `high` and `low` are on the index of the one number you're looking for, just like in traditional binary search. If my answer helped you, don't forget to accept the answer and/or upvote it!

Comment: I got it after taking notes with a pen and a paper. I did upvote your vote, it's just that I have low reputation apparently so it doesn't show it, but it says it has been recorded! Thank you!
Also, to find the value of the index, what's the best way to do it? I thought about an instance to represent it, such as 'found' from the previous code.

Comment: @Ohande Thank you, glad I could help. Once you have the index you can find the value outside of the method just by doing `array[index]`. What exactly you do with that value depends on what you need it for, but there's no need to do anything like the `found` variable you had before.

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion, the solution is really impressive, however, I found an edge case when `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown for inputs `{1, 2, 2}` or `{2, 2, 1}` in line `if (a[mid] != a[mid-1])`

Comment: @AlexRudenko Good catch! I've edited my answer with a solution that passes that test case.

Comment: @dbl as stated before, pairing numbers will always be next to each other so the first two arrays aren't viable, also there will always be a single number so the third one isn't either.

Comment: @dbl I have edited OP's question to add clarity. This algorithm has a complexity of O(log(n)) because each iteration through the loop eliminates half of positions where the single number could be.

Comment: Your edit haven't been approved yet. I've checked the execution of that solution and it is a binary search O(log(n)).